# Cordova 3.4 Import in Eclipse Error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Cordova, I followed one of the many tutorials and created the cordova android app through command line interface and After that, also created a plugin for device, but i am not able to properly import the whole app in Eclipse.
I understand that I have to edit the top level files, not the ones presented in the assets directory of the project in eclipse as these are created using the "build" command. These top level files don't exist in the project I've created in eclipse as they are above the root of the project.It doesn't show Android Reference Libraries and Cordova Library  in project in eclipse.I have already wasted more than a day, So please help me Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly the files imported in eclipse are the files in platforms/android wich as you mentionned are overwritten when you build the project using cordova cli.

What you can do is create a hook for the before_prepare step to copy your files from platform/android/assets/www to /www before the project is built. (and maybe the same to save for java and js files in your plugin)

Here are some links about cordova cli hooks :

- http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1197
- http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/